# Inequalities involving geometry but I can't post a picture yet

Tags: inequality

How do I show that
$$ \frac 12 \left(\frac 1 {3^2}+\frac 1{4^2}+ \frac 1{5^2}+\dots\right) < \frac 1 {3^2} + \frac 1{5^2} + \frac1{7^2} +\dots \quad ?$$

Comment: ... So when is that picture coming along?

Comment: Well i Dont have that 10 xp or watever it needs me to do to post a pic. Also this question is only one part of an entire question

Comment: Is the RHS the sum of the reciprocals of the squares of odd integers or the sum of the reciprocals of the squares of odd primes?

Comment: It is for the sum of odd integers

Comment: Type the link in and someone with higher reputation will post your picture

Answer (score 2):

After moving the odd terms from the LHS to the RHS, we obtain the following equivalent inequality,
$$\frac 12 \left(\frac 1{4^2}+ \frac 1{6^2}+ \frac 1{8^2}+\dots\right) < \left(1-\frac 12\right)\left( \frac 1 {3^2} + \frac 1{5^2} + \frac1{7^2} +\dots\right).$$
Then note that for all positive integer $n$, each term $\dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}$ is less than $\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$

Comment: How do you even type that latex thing up so fast lollls (i just got an account on this maths exchange thing)

Comment: I believe you would want to show 1/r^2 < 1/2 [1/(r-1)^2 + 1/(r+1)^2] if you know what I mean? for a general r

Comment: @D.Ronald I just moved the odd terms from the LHS to the RHS.

Comment: AHHHH GOT IT BOSS

Comment: @D.Ronald Well done. If you are new here take a few seconds for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: Note that the RHS:
$$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\cdots =\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\cdots \right)+\frac{1}{2^2}\left(\underbrace{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}\cdots}_{\frac{\pi^2}{6}} \right) \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2^2}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1.$$
The LHS:
$$\frac 12 \left(\frac 1 {3^2}+\frac 1{4^2}+ \frac 1{5^2}+\dots\right)=\frac12\cdot\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{5}{8}.$$
Hence:
$$\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{5}{8}<\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1 \iff 9<\pi^2.$$